Why is the induced charge on the infinite plane expected to be $-q$?
3.2.2 page 123 of Griffiths E&M.
Place a charge $q$ a distance of $d$ above an infinite grounding conducting plane. The total charge induced on the conducting plane is then $-q$.
The last sentence is "Evidently, the total charge induced on the plane is $-q$, as (with  benefit of hindsight) you can perhaps convince yourself it had to be.
Can somebody give me an intuitive explanation of why this is true? It seems like some of the field lines from the inducing charge go off in the other direction, and will never be "absorbed" by the infinite conducting plane; thus to me, it is surprising that the total charge induced is exactly the opposite of the inducing charge.

Perhaps this is a way to consider it.
Can't the same argument be made for the "induced" charge?  In other words, the mirror reflection of the inducing charge that "appears" a distance $d$ below the conducting plane will also have field lines that don't intersect the conducting plane.

I don't understand how this would imply that the total charge on the conducting plane is equal to the charge of the inducing plane
